# What's the difference between 'each...do' and 'do'

Tags: ruby

Just working on some practice problems but I'm confused what 'do' does exactly

```
self.length.times do |i|
```

What would the difference be between this code and

```
self.each do |i|
```

Answer (score 3):

`do ... end` code blocks (or mostly equivalent `{ ... }` blocks) in Ruby are an important language feature which allow you to pass some behavior (i.e. some block of code) to a method. If you known Javascript, you can think of Ruby's blocks a bit like an anonymous function as a first approximation.

Now, when passing a block to the `each` method, it will call the block once for each element in the enumeration, passing thew current element as the first argument of the block.

The `Integer#times` method also takes a block. It will call the block `n` times with a number as a argument, counting from 0 until `n - 1` (with `n` being whatever number you call the `times` method on. Thus, the block will be called exactly `n` times.

Since blocks are an integral part of Ruby which is used about everywhere, you should try to get a good understanding of how they work. You will find a lot of  guides and posts on Google if you search fir "ruby blocks".

Comment: “mostly equivalent `{ ... }` blocks”—it’s probably worth to mention that the only difference is precedence. `puts [1].each do |i| i end` would output an `Enumerator`, while `puts [1].each { |i| i }` outputs the result.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to post a couple of example.

Let's say `self` object is an [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html):

```
self_object = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

---

With the former option `self_object.length.times do |i|` you are calling [Array#length](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-length), which returns the Integer`3` and then calling [Integer#times](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Integer.html#method-i-times) on the integer `3` (`3.times`). This is the result:

```
self_object.length.times do |i|
  p i
end

# 0
# 1
# 2
```

---

With the last option you are just calling [Array#each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-each) on the array, so:

```
self_object.each do |i|
  p i
end

# "a"
# "b"
# "c"
```

---

`each` method applies to these objects ([see docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/)):

- ARGF,
- Array,
- Dir,
- Enumerator
- Enumerator::ArithmeticSequence,
- Enumerator::Chain
- Hash
- IO
- ObjectSpace::WeakMap
- Range
- Struct

Answer (score 1):

The difference is the value of `i`.

```
["one", "two", "three"].length.times do |i|
  puts i
end

0
1
2
```

and the other:

```
["one", "two", "three"].each do |i|
  puts i
end

one
two
three
```

As you can see, one returns the index of the loop, and the other the array item.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
self.length.times do |i|
```

`i` is just counting up numbers between 0 and `self.length - 1`.

With

```
self.each do |i|
```

`i` will take the value of each element of `self`.

Answer (score 0):

Both

```rb
self.each do |i|
```

and

```rb
self.length.times do |i|
```

are not valid Ruby.

In Ruby `do` is a keyword that starts a block. It **must** be followed by `end` keyword which ends a block. [Here is a good article](https://www.rubyguides.com/2016/02/ruby-procs-and-lambdas/) you can read about blocks, and how they relate to other similar Ruby constructs, like Procs and Lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is also good to say, how it actually works.

Let's have code

```rb
# could be also defined as with_env_variable_set_to_hello(&block)
def with_env_variable_set_to_hello
   fail ArgumentError unless block_given?

   origin = ENV['MY_VARIABLE']
   ENV['MY_VARIABLE'] = 'hello'
   yield # runs block here
   ENV['MY_VARIABLE'] = origin
end
```

Usage:

```rb
with_env_variable_set_to_hello do
   puts ENV['MY_VARIABLE'] # hello
end
```

Sometimes, you can use arguments passed to block, such like

```rb
items.each do |item|
  # do something
end
```

It is provided by giving argument to `yield` (&block)

```rb
def do_something
  yield 'arg1', :arg2, 3
end
```

Usage:

```rb
do_something do |string, symbol, integer|
  puts string, symbol, integer # 'arg1' :arg2 3
end
```